# React: remove event listener "beforeunload" doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to add a prompt when users leave the page without saving.

Here is my code:

```
    componentDidUpdate() {
        if (!this.props.data.get('is_data_saved')) {
            window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(e) {
                e.returnValue = 'Data may not be saved'
            }, true);
        } else {
            window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', function(e) {
                e.returnValue = 'Data may not be saved'
            }, true);
            console.log('REMOVED')
        }
    }
```

I got "REMOVED" in the console, but the prompt is always pop up even when the form had been saved. Is it because I put the event listener in the wrong component?

Comment: first of all your `removeEventListener` is obsolete as it does not remove the original function but a new function simply with same code. Second, is `this.props` the correct way to handle state changes or maybe state itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic problem i see is that you are adding and removing a different function.

You need to use a reference to an existing method, instead of rewrtitting the same code.

```
beforeUnloadHandler(e){
    e.returnValue = 'Data may not be saved';
}
componentDidUpdate() {
    if (!this.props.data.get('is_data_saved')) {
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.beforeUnloadHandler, true);
    } else {
        window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.beforeUnloadHandler, true);
        console.log('REMOVED')
    }
}
```

---

But if that component gets updated in other ways it could end up adding multiple event handlers. To avoid this you could either set a flag as well if the event handler is set, or be more defensive and always remove the handler first and re-add it if required.

Something like

```
beforeUnloadHandler(e){
    e.returnValue = 'Data may not be saved';
}
componentDidUpdate() {
    // always remove the handler
    window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.beforeUnloadHandler, true);
    // if required add it back
    if (!this.props.data.get('is_data_saved')) {
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.beforeUnloadHandler, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Gabriele, yes it is such a basic problem. It worked now

Comment: if you use react hook, maybe you need `useCallback` to persist handler reference :)